# elasticsearch use a custom 3rd party artifact

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle

How can I use a custom 3rd party artifact in ElasticSearch locally ?

From [docs](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/BUILDING.md#you-should-only-use-that-approach-locally-or-on-a-developer-branch-for-for-production-dependencies-as-we-donot-want-to-ship-unreleased-libraries-into-our-releases)

> Update the dependency declaration of the artifact in question to match
> the custom build version. For a file named e.g. jmxri-1.2.1.jar the
> dependency definition would be :jmxri:1.2.1 as it comes with no group
> information:

But I get an exception because `getGroup` returns null

---

Steps to reproduce

1. clone elasticseach into /tmp
2. create a directory /tmp/elasticsearch/localRepo
3. add to (root) build.gradle `allprojects`  [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/build.gradle#L162) the following

```
allprojects { 
  repositories {
      flatDir {
          dirs 'localRepo'
      }
  }
}
```

4. my local jar is /tmp/elasticsearc/localRepo/test-3.2.1.jar
5. add [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/e6f5cd3d9b9b282a06743a6d2b2af9de701d106c/client/sniffer/build.gradle#L41)

```
api ':test:3.2.1'
```

6. run `./gradlew localDistro`

Error message

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file '/tmp/elasticsearch/client/sniffer/build.gradle' line: 41

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':client:sniffer'.
> Cannot invoke "String.startsWith(String)" because the return value of "org.gradle.api.artifacts.Dependency.getGroup()" is null

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':client:sniffer'.
> Cannot invoke "java.lang.Comparable.compareTo(Object)" because the return value of "java.util.function.Function.apply(Object)" is null



BUILD FAILED in 925ms
19 actionable tasks: 19 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

Dependencies always need a group set like

```
"group:module:version"
```

You also need that for flatDir repositories but the group doesn't matter and can be anything as far as I know. I used "test" in the example below

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs(" /tmp/elasticsearch/localRepo")
    }
}
dependencies {
    api 'test:test:3.2.1'
}
```